# How to select and modify a "standalone" class?

Tags: jquery

In the bootstrap style sheet there are classes defined like:

```
.a { ... }
.b { ... }
.a>.b { .... }
```

I want to select `.b` and change its color, but I don't want this to affect the class `b` in `.a>.b`, ie I want the styles of `.a>.b` to remain unchanged.

Can this be done in jQuery?

Examples of `a` and `b` in bootstrap are `panel-default` and `panel-heading` respectively.

Comment: so you want to affect `b` whose parents are not `a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) pseudo-class selector to avoid certain elements.

**JQuery :**

```
$('.b:not(.a>.b)')
```

**CSS :**

```
.b:not(.a>.b){ ... }
```